# Dojo.query foreach accessing element value

Tags: ajax, dojo, spring-js

I'm a newbie in Dojo framework, so I hope my question is not really dumb.

I have a link in my web page :

```
<a href="#" value="${index}" name="delete_name" id="delete_id${index}">Delete</a>
```

The variable "index" is well defined, no issue with that.

Then, I've written this piece of code to add an action to the onclick event on my link and a JS function to call before the submit :

```
dojo.query("a[name=supprimerEnfant_name]").forEach(function(element) {
    Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.AjaxEventDecoration({
        formId: "form_id",
        elementId: element.id,
        event: "onclick",
        beforeSubmit: function(){
            jsFunctionToCall(element.value);
        },
        params: { _eventId: "deleteEvent", fragments:"frag"}
    }))
});
```

In my `jsFunctionToCall`, I can get the `element.id` (checked and it's OK) but the element's value is `null` and I can't figure out why.

I'm probably missing something important, could you help me with that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be aware that `element.value` only works with elements where it's part of the DOM, defined by W3C. So, if you look at the [`HTMLInputElement`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html) interface (used by form elements), you will see that it clearly has a property called `value`, referencing to the the value of the element.

**However**, the same is not true for an [HTMLAnchorElement](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element). This means the proper way to retrieve the value of the `value` attribute, is by selecting the attribute itself, using the `getAttribute()` function or by using the the [**dojo/dom-attr**](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/dom-attr.html) Dojo module.

For example:

```
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/domReady!"], function(query, domAttr) {
    query("a").forEach(function(element) {
        console.log(element.id);
        console.log(domAttr.get(element, "value")); // This will work
    });
});
```

Demonstration: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BW3Ga/)

Answer (score 1):

The dojo query will return the domNode references always. Anyhow, the anchor element is a HTML element. So, this is nothing to do with Dojo and lets see whats wrong with the JS part.

The "value" is **not a standard attribute** of anchor element. So, the additional attributes need to be accessed using **"getAttribute"** method.
i.e. in your case,

```
element.getAttribute('value')
```